# Transactions and nested Transactions in C#

Tags: c#, transactions

I read a lot of articles on Transaction but I want to build my own example of nested Transactions to see how it really works in c#. I already have a good idea about them in SQl but C# is giving me a tough time. SO I came here for an example that can explain how Nested Transactions work. 
I tried the following code to check if the inner transaction will be committed or not. Since the `TransactionScope` property is `RequiresNew` the inner transaction should execute but I introduced a deliberate `Unique key` violation in outer Transaction and my inner transaction didn't execute. Why? Is my concept messed up?

```
Database _Cataloguedatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

public void TransferAmountSuppress(Account a)
{
    var option = new TransactionOptions();
    option.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope outerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, option))
        {
            using (DbCommand cmd = _Cataloguedatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(SpUpdateCredit))
            {
                _Cataloguedatabase.AddInParameter(cmd, CreditAmountParameter, DbType.String, a.Amount);
                _Cataloguedatabase.AddInParameter(cmd, CodeParameter, DbType.String, a.Code);
                _Cataloguedatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
            using (TransactionScope innerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, option))
            {
                using (DbCommand cmd = _Cataloguedatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(SpUpdateDebit))
                {
                    _Cataloguedatabase.AddInParameter(cmd, DebitAmountParameter, DbType.String, a.Amount);
                    _Cataloguedatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
                }
                innerScope.Complete();
            }
            outerScope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText(ex.Message)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `_Cataloguedatabase` ? How is that using the transactionscopes?

Comment: If think in the inner scope the `_Cataloguedatabase` is using the transaction from the outer scope, or an entirely different one that was created before you called the method (since `_Cataloguedatabase` could have a transaction already, since `_Cataloguedatabase` was created outside of the method).

Comment: You said you have a good idea about SQL transactions, then you should know that inner transaction will not save data because outer transaction was not completed: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ . Which leads us to a question: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `_Cataloguedatabase` is the Enterprise Library's `Database` object(global)

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy The OP is using TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, which should create a new transaction. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: @Multistack I'm not that familiar with the enterprise library. Does it automatically enroll in an existing transaction(scope)? Is is *transaction scope aware*? [google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=enterprise+library+transactionscope+aware%3F)

Comment: @Maarten I know what TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew does but I don't see any sense in what author has written. SQL Server does not support commit of nested transaction. Why would it suddenly start working?

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy What does the TransactionScope property `RequiresNew` do? I thought this will create a new transaction(inner) which will be independent of outertransaction.(independently committed or rolled back )

Comment: @Multistack Correct AFAIK. The question I have now is: how does the `_Cataloguedatabase` know it should enlist in the transactionscope?

Comment: @Multistack then, obviously, you are not familiar with transactions in SQL Server. Read the article I posted above, it explains how nested transactions work (I don't say it works correctly or incorrectly, it is like it is). Also, if you need two independent transactions then you should write C# to create to separate transactions and not child-parent

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy The SQL executed by the C# code is not executed as a nested transaction AFAIK. It will create a new sql transaction (with a new sql connection possibly, not sure) when you use RequiresNew, and use it correctly. I've used RequiresNew before, and it is working fine. The thing is, you need to use it correctly, and I'm not sure that the OP is.

Comment: @Maarten sorry, I missed that he does not re-use connection, my fault. But in this case author is not experimenting with nested transactions like he wanted, he uses separate connections with separate transactions and code has to be written in the same way to reflect this logic.

Comment: @Maarten can you give an easy example of nested transaction of `RequiresNew` property?

Comment: @Multistack You current code is fine, with the exception that it is not clear how/if the `_Cataloguedatabase` is using transactionscope. If you were using Entity Framework, and put `using (var ctx = new EfContext()) { ... }` inside the transactionscope-using, it would work fine.

Comment: I just ran a small experiment on what author is trying to achieve. Yes, it is not nested transaction at all. Unfortunately I can't enable network access for DTS on my machine right now and can't test the behavior when child trx has just "Required".

Comment: How can you say its not a Nested Transaction? And how can I modify it inorder to make it nested Transaction?

Comment: OK, may be we have different view on terminology. For me "nested transaction" means that child transaction is bound to parent. Exactly how it is in SQL Server when you start a transaction inside another transaction. As you wrote "this will create a new transaction(inner) which will be independent of outertransaction". So, basically if you move code in inner scope to the beginning of try-statement, you should get exactly same behavior and without "nesting" (how you call it)